# Using regex_extract to loop through a string list Pyspark

Tags: python, regex, string, list, loops

I have a list full of strings.

```
List = ['NYC','Austin','San Diego', 'New Orleans','LA']
```

And I have this dataframe with one column , "raw" in it. All values in 'raw' are dictionary values. So sth like:

```
{'NYC':'COOL','Austin':'mild','San Diego':'hot','New Orleans':'cold','LA':'CHILL'}
```

I have this loop that I want to extract values from the "raw" column that has the strings in the list above using regex_extract and create a new column for each in Pyspark dataframe.

```
for field in list:
    df = df \
    .withColumn(field, F.regexp_extract("raw",''+urllib.quote(field)+':"([^"]*)"', 1))
```

But when I do this it doesn't work.

So final goal is to have all these columns  : 'raw', 'NYC','Austin','San Diego', 'New Orleans','LA'.

Would like to know how to take in parameter values in here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
schema = df.select(schema_of_json(df.select(regexp_replace('raw',' ','_')).first()[0])).first()[0]


df.select(from_json(regexp_replace('raw',' ','_'),schema).alias('data')).\
   select('data.*').show()

+------+-----+----+-----------+---------+
|Austin|   LA| NYC|New_Orleans|San_Diego|
+------+-----+----+-----------+---------+
|  mild|CHILL|COOL|       cold|      hot|
|  mild|CHILL|COOL|       cold|      hot|
+------+-----+----+-----------+---------+
```